How to count same values in 2 columns
I would like to compare data across multiple people and how often they are paired with one another at any given location.
Down below i attached an image.

To elaborate, for example, how could i compare Martin to Malte and have it give me the number of how many times they are at the same location.
Example:
Martin-Malte
Base: 12
Line: 5
Composite: 2
Sheet Metal: 0
Store: 0
Avionic: 2
Cabin: 7
And that for every pairing

I'm not quite following your ask. At face value you want to sum 2 countifs formulas; however, by your example that doesn't seem the case as there isn't 12 Base under those 2 names, there's only 9? No instances of Cabin. Can you clarify what the actual calculation is supposed to be? How are these pairings determined?

Your example doesn't meet your image. But it's advisable to post your data as data (markdown table) besides the image.
